# pipenv : how to force virtualenv directory?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Actually, pipenv will install the virtualenv with a path like this :

```
$WORKON_HOME/<base_dir>-<hash>
```

Is it possible to have exactly the path I want, that is without the `base_dir` and the `hash`, for exemple :

```
/home/user/myapp_venv
```

Comment: `$ virtualenv /home/user/myapp_venv`?

Comment: by using pipenv command of course !

Comment: `pipenv` is not intended to create arbitrary envs, that's what `virtualenv` is for. However, you can use already created envs with `pipenv` as shown in the answer.

Comment: @hoefling `pipenv` locks dependencies with a `Pipenv.lock` file. If you just use `virtualenv`, you won't have that benefit, and you could run into unexpected differences when you install the requirements to different environments. So there's a valid case for using `pipenv` for this purpose.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an [undocumented feature](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1532) of pipenv, it could locate virtualenv path from `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable, but you need to create virtualenv manually:

```
virtualenv /home/user/myapp_venv
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/user/myapp_venv pipenv install
```

Answer (score 29):

Apart from using a custom location, you can also install the virtualenv in your project's directory. Just add the following line in your .bashrc/.zshrc file:

```sh
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
```

Just wanted to let others know that there is another approach available too.

Should you keep the virtualenv inside or outside the project's directory is an opinionated question afterall.

Comment: how do you do this in windows?

Comment: @TonyS under windows, create an environment variable with same name, i.e. `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` and set its value to 1. I haven't tested this as I don't have a windows machine, but this should work.

Answer (score 14):

There's an undocumented feature in `pipenv`: if you [create a file named `.venv` in the project root with a path in it](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/ebdf1ff8de76a2884d4698d81193630602c3cdca/pipenv/project.py#L233-L247), `pipenv` will use that instead of an autogenerated path.

This, however, [is more fit for cases when you already have an established set of environments that you wish to reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892572/keeping-the-same-shared-virtualenvs-when-switching-from-pyenv-virtualenv-to-pip). Otherwise, placing environments in arbitrary places is prone to create a mess eventually. `pipenv` relieves you from this task specifically to keep them all in one predictable place and eliminate accidental collisions from human error.

Comment: I think you mean folder not file .. and yes it is worked.

Comment: @DAMAR225 No, I specifically mean a file. Its contents need to be a path to the environment directory. If you create a directory `.venv`, it itself will be used for an environment. But the OP asks for an arbitrary path.

Comment: Being undocumented is interesting, and the two links in your post seem to take us to an unrelated code block. This appears to be a more useful link: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/0a03b7660226252a0d3eba94231164d7346db92c/pipenv/project.py#L226 and reveals .venv can be file or directory in fact.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, Pycharm user by

1. make .venv fold in project
2. Settings->Project->Project interpreter->pipenv Environment

it works for me

Answer (score -1):

Creating a directory .venv in the project then try to initiate with `pipenv install <some package>` did not work for me at the first in my mac, it was always creating virtual environment somewhere else. Though later I figure it out the reason. The hack is, first `cd` to the project folder `cd /Home/.../MyProject` then create a empty Pipfile `touch Pipfile` the create a directory `mkdir .venv` should work. Now you can run `pipenv install` and .venv folder will be used.

Now the elaboration is given form the source [code](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/pipenv/project.py#L288). When the pipenv try to create create a virtual env it looks to the directory `dot_venv = os.path.join(self.project_directory, ".venv")` (taken from source code) and thats how the `self.project_directory` looks like:

```
@property
    def project_directory(self):
        # type: () -> str
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.pipfile_location, os.pardir))
```

So that function looks for the pipfile location to create the path it will create the virtual environment. So if you create the empty `Pipfile` before hand it is confirmed that it will find that file and then find the .venv directory and create the path all together.