# Keeping the same, shared virtualenvs when switching from pyenv-virtualenv to pipenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv

I started looking at `pipenv` and it seems to be pretty good. My only concern is, that most of my projects involve `numpy`, `scipy` and some other not-so-small libraries.

**The current way manage my projects:**
I have `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` installed. I have a few (currently 4) specific `virtualenvs` that each cater to a *type* of project. The projects themselves have `.pyenv-version` set, I have the autoload virtualenv feature of `pyenv` enabled. If I need to share a project, I generate a `requirements.txt` with `pip freeze -l` from the `virtualenv`.

So in my current setup, I have `X` number of projects and `Y, Y << X` number of `virtualenvs`, all amounting to a few GB of harddisk space. Note that because of large libraries like `numpy` each of the `virtualenvs` are pretty big, around 700-900 MB.

**My question:**

As far as I understand, `pipenv` will, by default create a `virtualenv` for all of my projects, so the harddisk space taken up by my `virtualenvs` would increase considerably. What I'm interested in is:

- is it possible to share `pipenv` environments across several projects, that use *exactly* the same dependencies? i.e. multiple `pipenv` configs that load the same `virtualenv`?
- if not, is it possible to generate `pipenv` config files from a `virtualenv` I set up with `pyenv`? i.e. I would not use `pipenv` to actually run my projects, I would not create any `virtualenvs` with `pipenv`, but I would create `pipenv` config files for sharing the project (in this case, probably along side a `requirements.txt` as well).

**edit**:
I rewrote most of the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`pipenv` doesn't seem to be a good fit for your specific workflow because it's project-centric rather than environment-centric.** `pipenv` treats a virtual environment as volatile and reserves the right to alter it freely if circumstances call for it. **You can use it but in the case of alterations to your environments, it will be a pain to keep all projects synchronized due to `pipenv`'s stricter scrunity.**

You *can* explicitly specify a virtual environment for `pipenv` to use for a project [by creating a `.venv` file in the project root with a path to it](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/pipenv/project.py#L287-L294) (normally, virtualenvs are created in a specific location with autogenerated names that include a hash of the path to the project). This seems to be undocumented.

However, `pipenv`, unlike `virtualenv`, checks and enforces that the virtual environment has the exact set of modules satisfying conditions in `Pipfile` and the exact "last tested configuration" specified in a generated `Pipfile.lock`.

- Besides, if you generate `Pipfile` from `requirements.txt`, it will specify exact package versions and include all dependencies -- [while by design, it's supposed to contain more intelligent information.](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt)

So, if you change any package version in an environment, you'll need to:

- update all `Pipfile.lock`s in affected projects (e.g. copy the changed one). With a generated `Pipfile`, you may get away with deleting them instead.
- update all `Pipfile`s in affected projects to the new package versions (e.g. copy the changed one) if there was a change

Comment: I updated the question considerably, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @fbence finally found time to dig into the source and find a conclusive answer. See the update.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much for going so far as to dig into the source! This actually doesn't look impossible to manage, even if I must agree, that unless you have very big environments, it's not worth it :)